# Is it possible to store a pseudo SQL Server database for my ASP .NET project?

Tags: asp.net

My ASP.NET project is using SQL Server as the database. I am wondering if it is possible to store a temporary instance of my database so that I would only need to query once to work with the data that I need. For example, I will query the 2 tables, `Person` and `Students` with a common id. I want to be able to join the tables and use the information.

I think there are some solutions:

1. Store the tables in the front end and use ajax javascript to manipulate the tables information.
2. Store in a txt file or similar file on to the project folder as a pseudo database.

Would love to hear any ideas!

Comment: This is static data that won't change? You could just hard-code it into data structures in your code rather than reading it from the database if there's not very much. If you do need to modify it then it might be simplest to just use the embedded SQL Server since it'll handle all the concurrency issues etc. for you and will scale. Is there a particular reason you want to drop the SQL Server?

Comment: Why not store the information in your backend code, use the same controllers as if you were reading the info from the db. That way later when you do need to attach it to a db you just need to switch out your temp objects in code to the db. What is the actual reason you have to work this way though?

Comment: Basically, there are unexpected issues with the current SQL Server that i may have to consider an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You could do worse than consider SQL Server Compact edition:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=17876

Which *has a small footprint and supports private deployment of its binaries within the application folder*

EDIT:

It seems CE is deprecated since last I used it. and MS now recommend SQL Server Express Local DB

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

And there is also SQLLite: https://www.supinfo.com/articles/single/6941-an-aspnet-core-mvc-app-with-sqlite-and-entity-framework

Comment: Thank you Matthew for taking time to help me with this.I think both solutions suggest a replacement for MSSQL, but i have all my data in MSSQL. I was thinking is it possible to have a localDB instance being ran along with my MSSQL